# Help in understanding the proof of Mersenne Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem:
$$\text{ If } 2^{n} - 1 \text{ is prime then n is prime}$$

**Proof 1:**
$$\text{If } n = kl \text{ with } 2 \leq k, l < n \text{ then } (2^{k} - 1)|(2^{n} - 1). \text{ Hence if } 2^{n} - 1 \text{ is prime, n must be prime }$$

**Proof 2**: Using the identity:
$$2^{n} - 1 = ( 2 - 1 )( 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + ... + 1 )$$

$$\text{ Let }n = rs, \text{ then } 2^{n} - 1 = ( 2^{r} - 1 )( 2^{r(s-1)} + 2^{r(s-2)} + ... + 1 )$$ 
$$\text{ However each factor on the right exceeds 1 contradicting with the fact that } 2^{n} - 1 \text{ is prime }$$ 
Hence, n is prime.

Proof 1: I have no idea what the author's purpose.

Proof 2: I understood a little bit. Can anyone help me explain why n must be prime? I am totally lost with the above proofs. If we let $ n = rs $, then what can we say about $n$ with $2^{n} - 1$ is prime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the proofs are the same. This is an example of a proof by transposition or proof by contrapositive where you prove the contrapositive.

The statement $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to the statement $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.

Hence, proving $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to proving $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.

The statement $A$ in your problem is "$2^n - 1$ is a prime" and the statement $B$ in your problem is "$n$ is a prime".

In this context, we have "If $2^n - 1$ is a prime, then $n$ is a prime".

The contrapositive is "If $n$ is not a prime then $2^n - 1$ is not a prime".

The author now proves the contrapositive statement. Hence, the author takes $n$ to be not a prime i.e. he takes $n$ to be a composite number.

Since $n$ is a composite number, $n$ can be written as $n = kl$, where $2 \leq k,l < n$.

So $2^n - 1 = 2^{kl} - 1 = (2^k)^l-1$.

Now observe that $(a-1)|(a^l - 1)$, $\forall l \in \mathbb{N}$.

This can be seen from the remainder theorem or by factorizing $(a^l - 1) = (a-1) (a^{l-1} + a^{l-2} + \cdots + a + 1)$.

Note that $2 < 2^k-1 < 2^n-1$ since $2 \leq k<n$ and plug in $a=2^k$, we get $((2^k)^l - 1) = ((2^k)-1) ((2^k)^{l-1} + (2^k)^{l-2} + \cdots + (2^k) + 1)$. Hence, we have $(2^k - 1)|(2^n-1)$, which implies $2^n-1$ is a composite number.

Hence, we have "If $n$ is not a prime then $2^n - 1$ is not a prime" which implies the contrapositive i.e. "If $2^n - 1$ is a prime, then $n$ is a prime".

**Note**

Say, we denote the original statement by $A$.

Let $A$ be the statement "If $2^n - 1$ is a prime, then $n$ is a prime"

Let $B$ be the statement "If $n$ is not a prime, then $2^n-1$ is not a prime"

Let $C$ be the statement "If $2^n-1$ is not a prime, then $n$ is not a prime"

Let $D$ be the statement "If $n$ is a prime, then $2^n - 1$ is a prime"

Statements $A$ and $B$ are contrapositives of each other. So if $A$ is true then so is $B$ and if $B$ is true then so is $A$.

Similarly, Statements $C$ and $D$ are contrapositives of each other.  So if $C$ is true then so is $D$ and if $D$ is true then so is $C$.

Statements $C$(equivalently statement $D$) and $A$(equivalently statement $B$) are converses of each other. In general, we cannot conclude that if a statement is true then its converse is true and we cannot conclude that if a converse is true then the statement is true.

In this example, statement $A$(equivalently statement $B$) is true.

However, statements $C$(equivalently statement $D$) which is the converse of statement $A$(equivalently statement $B$) is false.

An example is $2^{11} - 1 = 2047 = 23 × 89$ is not a prime but $11$ is a prime. So $C$(equivalently statement $D$) is false.

Comment: Very good and detailed answer, +1.

Comment: Ambikasaran: Many thanks for your great effort ;) ! I feel less dumb now.

Comment: @Chan: The reason why I explained the question in depth, is that I usually like to play with people's reasoning in day to day conversations using this seemingly simple statement, $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$. You will be surprised to hear so many people getting confused on this fact and drawing illogical conclusions :). It is actually fun to have them think about this.

Answer (score 4):

The essence of the matter is the following: $\rm\ f\:(gcd(n,m))\ =\ gcd(f(n),f(m))\ $ for $\rm\ f(n)\ =\ 2^n-1\:$. Because the map $\rm\:f\:$ preserves gcds it must preserve many multiplicative properties (e.g. primes). You can find  further discussion and proofs in my [posts here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1/7561#7561). If you go on to study *divisor theory* then these properties will become crystal clear.

Comment: That is a different way of writing it. I like it!

Comment: @Eric: We have Kronecker to thank for the beautiful theory of divisors. It deserves to be much better known.